# human detection using live video feed from mobile platform (android)

Tags: android, image-processing, mobile, opencv, video-streaming

I have a requirement where I need to detect human prescence from a live video feed which is coming from a phones camera

I was wonering if this was possible from the phone itself on an android phone (latest models such as the HTC Desire HD and higher perhaps)? And if possible can anyone guide me to a place (with links or such) to get an idea on how to proceed

However if this was not possible from within the phone itself is it possible to take a live video stream from the phone and transmit it to a server, which for example process the feed using open cv and sends an output back to the phone, can anyone tell me if the transmission of the live video feed to a server is possible and any guidance is appreciated as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Half the world is looking for an efficient way to do that. Welcome to the club.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out
https://github.com/billmccord/OpenCV-Android

It may not be the most convenient thing to set up. But seems like it would work.

This might be helpful too.
http://www.slideshare.net/pickerweng/opencv-220-for-android